# How do we set different header and footer in user login and registration page in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

How do we set different header and footer in user login and registration page in Drupal? I am not asking about customizing the form. Am asking how to set completely different header and footer just as we can set page--node--[type].tpl.php.

Answer (score 0):

- page--user--login.tpl.php
- page--user--register.tpl.php

Both should work, after cache clearing!